# Seaborn 'set_theme' raises an attribute error

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn, data-visualization, data-analysis

I have a problem running `set_theme()` in Jupyter notebook: it raises the error `Module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'set_theme'`. This is the content of the cell raising the error:

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme()
```

I tried upgrading seaborn, as well as reinstalling it with `pip3 install seaborn==0.11.0` without any success.

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Works for me, which versions of python, ipython/jupyter are you using?

Comment: @PaulBrennan this is the version of python which I am using ( Python 3.8.3 )

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: Double check: are you using Jupyter? If so, did you install before import? If not, restart the kernel, install it first then import it.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'set_theme'    I get only this error when I run those two line of code

Comment: Have you restarted the kernel after upgrading/reinstalling `seaborn`?

Comment: yes I did ! Still no luck

Comment: Perhaps your Jupyter was using a different kernel from the one to which your `pip3` points to? Try changing the kernel, or executing the above lines in IPython.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem until I made a new Conda environment (https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/) and did
pip3 install seaborn==0.11.0 in this environment.